# crypto missing global variable name

Tags: javascript, cryptography, uuid, svelte, svelte-component

I have to move a component from svelte-sapper to sapper.
The component uses uuid in this way

```
import { v4 as uuidv4} from uuid
```

I installed also crypto. When i use that component on the console browser i have this error

rng.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomFillSync is not a function

and on the console:

```
bundles src/index.js → dist/index.mjs, dist/index.js, public/build/bundle.js...
(!) Missing global variable names
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
crypto (guessing 'crypto')
crypto (guessing 'crypto')
```

I already installed crypto with npm, the function is on bundle.js

```
const rnds8 = new Uint8Array(16); function rng() { return crypto.randomFillSync(rnds8); }
```

I saw that i need to use inside rollup.config.js, inside plugin element

```
resolve({ browser: true }),
```

But it did not work. Any suggestions?

---

here there is my rollup

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from './package.json';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

const name = pkg.name
    .replace(/^(@\S+\/)?(svelte-)?(\S+)/, '$3')
    .replace(/^\w/, m => m.toUpperCase())
    .replace(/-\w/g, m => m[1].toUpperCase());

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: [
        { file: pkg.module, 'format': 'es' },
        { file: pkg.main, 'format': 'umd', name },
        {
            sourcemap: true,
            format: 'iife',
            name: 'app',
            file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
            }
        }),
        resolve({
            browser: true
        }),
        commonjs(),
        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve()
    ]
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: In default Svelte template, I get exactly the same error as you if I remove `browser: true` from `resolve` plugin. Otherwise it just works, with no config change at all. So I think your option is not taken into account somehow (typo?)... Can you post your `rollup.config.js`?

Comment: i posted my rollup on the main

Comment: Well... Still working just by copy pasting your config in a freshly clone Svelte template, no changes. You don't need to install `crypto` package for that. No idea why it doesn't work for you :-/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error as you are having. Solved it by adding

```
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';
```

Then adding

```
nodePolyfills(),
resolve({
  browser: true,
})
```

This removed the warning for me